# Getting strings from database with encoding problems in outfile

Tags: python, mysql, json, string, encoding

i'm tryng to get some tweet data from a MySql database.
I've got tons of encoding errors while i was developing this code. This last for is the only way i got for running the code and getting this outfile full with \uxx characters all around, as you can see here:

```
[{..., "lang_tweet": "es", "text_tweet": "Recuerdo un d\u00eda de, *llamada a la 1:45*, \"Micho, me va a dar algo, estoy temblando, me tome un moster y un balium... Que me muero.!!\",...},...]
```

I've been here around and around trying different solutions, but the thing is that i got really confused with the abstraction of coding and encoding.
What can i do for fixing this?
Or maybe would be easier to just grab the dirty JSON and 'parse' it decoding those characters manually.

If you want take a look to the code i'm using to querying the db:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import pymysql
import collections
import json

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='sut', passwd='r', db='tweetsjun2016')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(""" 
            SELECT * FROM 20160607_tweets
            WHERE 20160607_tweets.creation_date >= '2016-06-07 10:51'
            AND 20160607_tweets.creation_date <= '2016-06-07 11:51'
            AND 20160607_tweets.lang_tweet = "es"
            AND 20160607_tweets.has_keyword = 1
            AND 20160607_tweets.rt = 0
            LIMIT 20
            """)

objects_list = []
for row in cur:
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    d['download_date'] = row[1]
    d['creation_date'] = row[2]
    d['id_user'] = row[5]
    d['favorited'] = row[7]
    d['lang_tweet'] = row[10]
    d['text_tweet'] = row[11].decode('latin1')
    d['rt'] = row[12]
    d['rt_count'] = row[13]
    d['has_keyword'] = row[19]

    objects_list.append(d)
    # print(row[11].decode('latin1')) <- looks perfect, it prints with accents and fine


j = json.dumps(objects_list, default=date_handler, encoding='latin1')
objects_file = "test23" + "_dicts"
f = open(objects_file,'w')
print >> f, j

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

If i delete the `*.decode('latin1')` method from all it's applications i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 51, in <module>
    j = json.dumps(objects_list, default=date_handler)
  File "C:\Users\Vichoko\Anaconda2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 251, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Vichoko\Anaconda2\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Vichoko\Anaconda2\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 13: invalid continuation byte
```

I really can't figure out the way the string is comming from the db to my script.

Thanks for reading, any idea would be thankfull.

Edit1:
Here you can see how the JSON files are being exported with the codification error in the text `text_tweet` key-val:
https://github.com/Vichoko/real-time-twit/blob/master/auto_labeling/json/tweets_sismos/tweetsago20160.json

Comment: I'm starting to think that would be easier to just **parse** the oufile and find the regex `\u[a-f0-9]+`and replace it with the corresponding value. Wich language or tool you recomend to do something like this? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `charset` keyword argument to `connect` as shown in the [example on pymysql's github](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/#id4).

Comment: surprisingly if i put to  `conect` the arg `charset='utf8mb4'`, and i delete the `.decode('latin1'))` decodings, and the posterior `json.dump` `encoding='latin1'` set to 'utf-8'; i get the same output strings in the outfile: `"text_tweet": "Cuando as\u00ed", `

Comment: @VicenteOyanedel - Can you get `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` so we can see what is actually stored.

Comment: @RickJames Sure, i executed that query for the `tweet_text` column and got this response: `| text_tweet  | HEX(20160801_tweets.text_tweet)
| Que fue lo que provocó el sismo en la Ciudad de México, un nuevo desgajamiento en santa fe | 51756520667565206C6F207175652070726F766F63C3B320656C207
369736D6F20656E206C6120436975646164206465204DC3A97869636F2C20756E206E7565766F2064657367616A616D69656E746F20656E2073616E7461206665 |`
As you can see the accents and LAT characters looks fine in the query. I hope  you can decode the HEX for what you want to know.

Comment: I managed to isolate `4D C3A9 78 69 63 6F` as the valid utf8 encoding for `México`.  The Unicode codepoint for `é` is `00E9`; you should not see that.  The data in the table is 'correct'; the fetching of it is incorrect.

Comment: @VicenteOyanedel - and is the problem only occurring when you do `json.dump`?  Of so, then don't use that function.

Comment: @RickJames Is no only a problem of `json,dump`. When i recieve the text from the cursor (directly from the db), and i print it with python i recieve this string with other type of character problems:`u'Se registr\xf3 sismo 4.4 en M\xe9rida'` (i deduce with the context`\xf3` it's ó and `\xe9` it's é).

Comment: F3 and E9 are the _latin1_ encodings for those accented letters; check out my notes here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for all the help, i read your notes but i didn't get what should i do to fix it. Right now i tried to decode the strings with the 'latin-1' decoder, just doing this `u'Se registr\xf3 sismo 4.4 en M\xe9rida'.decode('latin-1')` and it pops out this error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)`. Maybe it isn't that codification, or i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I think:  `u'` says that the string is utf8-encoded, but `f3` says that it is really latin1-encoded

Answer (score 0):

When using `json_encode`, add this extra parameter:

```
$t = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

That will give you `í` instead of `\u00ed`.

(Don't use regexps, don't use decode functions, etc., they will only dig your hole deeper.)

Comment: Hey Rick, thanks for your answer! Where should i add that? Note that i'm not using json_encode explicitly, just using the enconder of the dumper. Also, the code your wrote doesn't seem python, what is it?

Comment: @VicenteOyanedel - Oh.  That's PHP code.  I have no idea where it is happening.